# ZEPHYR RTOS Configuring GPIO Pins

Tags: embedded-linux, gpio, device-tree, zephyr-rtos

Hi I would like to configure a custom GPIO pin as output to control a motor on a STM32 H743Zi board running Zephyr RTOS.

The dts file of the board can be found in the [folder](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Vf9VEkpT_a9_drTIr7VKIisSCv4wlobR?usp=sharing) or a separate file [nucleo h743zi.dts](https://pastebin.com/AYg3VeT8) `code`.

I would like to us the arduino pin mapping provided by the board [ardunio r3 connector.dtsi](https://pastebin.com/HhBWfv7A) `code`

The overlay file that I've developed so far is as [follows](https://pastebin.com/yzGyQFYi)  `code`. I would like to configure the D0 pin (as per the arduino connector dtsi file) as a GPIO pin to control the motors.

However, I've not been able to configure the pin and I don't receive a high signal if the pin is turned on.

Any help to resolve this issue is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the answer in this link:
`https://github.com/zephyrproject-rtos/zephyr/discussions/35932`

In my case, I use Thunderboard Sensor 2 and my solution as below:

1. Move to the <board.dsti> in folder /zephyr/dts/arm/silabs/efr32mg.dtsi
   insert your define GPIO to use:

   ```
    ...
    / {
    zephyr,user {
        signal-gpios = <&gpioa 8 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
    };
    ...
   ```

Here, I use my board portA and pin 8 as schematic

2. After you save the file, open the main file of your project and insert something as below:

   ```
    #define ZEPHYR_USER_NODE DT_PATH(zephyr_user)
    ...
    void main(void)
   {
    const struct gpio_dt_spec signal = 
    GPIO_DT_SPEC_GET(ZEPHYR_USER_NODE, signal_gpios);
    /* Configure the pin */
    gpio_pin_configure_dt(&signal, GPIO_OUTPUT_INACTIVE);
    ...
       while(1){
        /* Toggle the pin PA8*/
        gpio_pin_toggle(signal.port, signal.pin);
        k_msleep(SLEEP_TIME_MS);
       }
   ...
   ```